# relate Android directories to storage

Tags: android, android-file

In storage setting, I could see 1.22GB/2.2GB free, however in manage app setting, I see only 129MB free while another 0.93GB is occupied. These numbers just don't add up. This drove me determined to get to the bottom of Android's file/storage structure. So in order to fully understand this, can anyone first show me the difference between phone storage and internal storage and internal SD card?  I came across these terms quite often, but am still quite confused how they actually were used. In addition, would you please directly show me what directories in Android are mapped to internal storage, and what directories are for external directories. Thanks

Comment: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/....

Comment: no this is too general. I need a detailed mapping